# calling method inside a method which takes some argument

Tags: python, function, oop, methods, nameerror

I am doing object oriented programming and quite new to it. I have defined classes and methods but I am facing some problem when I try to call one method which takes some argument into another method.It gives me: `NameError: name 'time' is not defined`.

Below is the snippet of my code.

```
@dataclass
class Stage:
    id: int
    production_equipment: List[ProductionEquipment] | None = None
    transfer_equipment: List[TransferEquipment] | None = None

    def completed_transfer_tasks(self, time: int):

        if self.transfer_equipment is not None:

            completed_transfer_task_ids = []

            for equipment in self.transfer_equipment:

                if equipment.transfer_tasks is not None:

                    for task in equipment.transfer_tasks:

                        if time - task.start_time >= task.min_transfer_duration:
                            completed_transfer_task_ids.append(task.id)

            return completed_transfer_task_ids

        else:

            print('Stage has TransferEquipment None')
```

I am trying to use this method in another one like below:

```
 def transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks(self):

        production_task_ids = self.unassigned_production_tasks_in_stage2and3()
        transfer_task_ids = self.completed_transfer_tasks(time)

        for id in production_task_ids:
            if id in transfer_task_ids:
                return id

        return None
```

When I try to call this method like below,

```
stage2 = Stage(2, [equipment1], [equipment2, equipment3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stage2.completed_transfer_tasks(70)
    x = stage2.transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks()
    print(x)
```

I am not sure if I am referencing the method in correct sense or not?

I tried giving time parameter initially, but this is not to be expected as it should be defined as an argument.

I think I am missing some syntax of calling methods which I am unable to rectify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no object named `time` in the scope of `transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks` function.
You should first bind an object to this name then you can use it.

You can set `time` as an object variable in the `completed_transfer_tasks` function, and then try to access it through the object itself in the `transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks` method.

```py
@dataclass
class Stage:
    id: int
    production_equipment: List[ProductionEquipment] | None = None
    transfer_equipment: List[TransferEquipment] | None = None

    def completed_transfer_tasks(self, time: int):
        self._time = time        
        if self.transfer_equipment is not None:

            completed_transfer_task_ids = []

            for equipment in self.transfer_equipment:

                if equipment.transfer_tasks is not None:

                    for task in equipment.transfer_tasks:

                        if time - task.start_time >= task.min_transfer_duration:
                            completed_transfer_task_ids.append(task.id)

            return completed_transfer_task_ids

        else:

            print('Stage has TransferEquipment None')
```

```py
 def transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks(self):

        production_task_ids = self.unassigned_production_tasks_in_stage2and3()
        transfer_task_ids = self.completed_transfer_tasks(self._time)

        for id in production_task_ids:
            if id in transfer_task_ids:
                return id

        return None
```

Comment: ` def transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks(self):

        production_task_ids = self.unassigned_production_tasks_in_stage2and3()
        transfer_task_ids = self.completed_transfer_tasks(...)  # whatever it should be

        for id in production_task_ids:
            if id in transfer_task_ids:
                return id

        return None`                                                                                                                                      time is an int datatype and there is no specific value to it.

Comment: Where does `time` come from in the code? It apparently comes from an input argument for your class's  `__init__`. You should set it as an object variable, then try to access it using object.

Comment: I have a dataclass. I have edited the question. Where do I set time as an object?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I am getting the below error.                                                       transfer_task_ids = self.completed_transfer_tasks(self._time = time)
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Comment: @MargiShah No, If you have already set the `self._time` variable in the `completed_transfer_tasks`, you need to only access it directly. Like this: `self.completed_transfer_tasks(self._time)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253189/discussion-between-amir-reza-riahi-and-margi-shah).